# Correct way to simulate and visualize 230V AC voltage in LTSpice IV

Tags: ac, ltspice

I want to simulate a 230V ac power supply in LTSpice IV. Apparently LTSpice requires to input the voltage amplitude in some special format - e.g. for 230V you have to input 325 as amplitude (at least that's what some credible posts on forums suggest). However, if I simulate such a power source, I get the voltage wave up to 325V, whereas I want the results to be in 230V format.

So, does LTSpice require the AC voltage amplitude in some special format?
If so, how do I get the correct visual plot results?

Comment: 230V RMS sinewave has a peak voltage around 325V (actually sqrt(2) * 230V.

Comment: @Brian thank you, that's the sad part about this, I've been living in lies

Comment: No lies, its origins were just a way to set a fair price. Think about 230V AC. Sometimes it's 325V. Sometimes it's -325V. Sometimes it's zero. Sometimes (4 times per cycle) it's even 230V... But if you're paying for 230V power, you want to get the same average power you'd get from a 230V DC supply. From that basic point, it follows (via a bit of math) you need 230V RMS, and from that, you get 325V peak.

Comment: @Brian and that are the lies I have been living in, because, either I have some serious mental issues or my physics teacher totally forgot to talk about this, so I lived in my nice ordered world - which it is not

Comment: Your physics course may have been deficient, LOL! But if you understand the origin (fair pricing) then the reasoning will make sense, and you have a solid understanding from now on.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see and understand the logic, but I don't get it why LTSPICE does not give me an option to get fake - fair priced results. I have an outlet with 230V, I plan to switch a 700uF capacitor before my 6kW heater, I simulate this in LTSPICE, I want to see the results. Then I will do dangerous stuff with real power supply and I will test the voltage with my voltmeter. And I would have wondered, why are the results so different. Ok, ok, I will consult a professional electrician and ask him to connect the capacitor, if he agrees.

Comment: That's not Spice, that's the way the models are written. It shouldn't be hard to write a Spice model that took an RMS voltage parameter for convenience.  (Though LTSpice being free, may have restrictions) p.s. that's quite some capacitor! The ones I know in that range are bipolar electrolytic, and rated for less than 30 seconds continuous use, for starting AC motors...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Well, your comment "that's quite some capacitor" explains why I can't find a lot of matching capacitors to choose from. But that's the capacitor I need to reduce 6kW heater to slightly above 5kW. Of course, I need it to work continuously for hours and hours. Your comment suggests nothing good...

Comment: aha! X/Y problem. Now we get to the real question "how do I reduce my heater power by 20%?" ... not by a series capacitor. Autotransformer (tap changer, variac ) would be an answer up to the 3kw level but quite expensive in your case : instead you need some kind of regulator, probably a zero volt switching triac or SSR (solid state relay) , that disconnects power 20% of the time.

Comment: @BrianDrummond But the capacitor solution works great in the simulation, it must work in reality ;-) Ok, so I understand that it probably is not possible to get a 700uF capacitor for 10h load time. I will receive my heater after a week, then I will check my options to increase my power line from 25A to 40A, if that fails I will look for other solutions. But the capacitor solution would have been just perfect.

Comment: @BrianDrummond those solutions with 20% disconnection time wont help, because the restriction is the maximum load on my power supply. 6kW at 230V is 26A, but my power supply has a circuit breaker with 25A. So even a short time at full power would trigger the circuit breaker, except if the heater is not able to draw the full 6kW immediately, then it might be a solution.

Comment: Oh. If you're just worried about input power, (a) breakers aren't precision instruments and a 25A breaker probably won't trip often at 30A let alone 26A. (b) Don't know where you are, but in the UK 30A and even 40A breakers are common (used for "7kw" and "10kw" water heaters). If your wiring is up to the job, you may not have a problem to solve.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am sure here in Latvia circuit breakers are more precise than in UK ;-)
About 30A breakers - are you sure there are 30A breakers that fit EU standard racks? I was looking for a 30A breaker all across the internet and the single one I found is in Saudi Arabia from GHala Sa.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the inhouse wire will be a 5x2.5mm2(so that I can change to a 3-phase heater in the future) where 4 wires will be combiined for the phase and the one for ground.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the only 30A circuit breakers I find on Amazon UK are some in a very special form, those won't fit in the breaker panel

Comment: My mistake : the "30A" breakers seem to have been standardised at 32A, which you can probably find. (the 30A ones I can find are an older type). But see also http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1951762.pdf which shows "Tripping Characteristics" (page 3) as non-tripping current = 1.05 * nominal for a type K breaker, but 1.13 * nominal for a type B. So I believe with careful choice of breaker you can work around the problem.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for the additional information. If I understand it right, then a 25A breaker has a non-tripping current of 28.25A(25x1.13). So if my heater draws up to 26A (6kW at 230V) then a 25A breaker should be ok :-o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 230V is RMS voltage, which for a sine wave, is \$\frac{V_{PEAK}}{\sqrt{2}}\$. SPICE takes the voltage as peak volts, so whatever RMS sine wave voltage you want, just multiply it by ~1.414 and use that.

You may as well get used to converting back and forth between RMS, peak, and peak-to-peak voltage- you'll need to do so early and often.

230V RMS, 325V peak and 650V peak-to-peak all describe the **same sine wave**.

Frequency is given in Hz rather than radians/second, but you'll also often have to convert between frequency and angular frequency (by multiplying by \$2\cdot\pi\$ for angular frequency since there are \$2\pi\$ radians in a circle ).

[Here](http://denethor.wlu.ca/ltspice/#vsin) is an introductory tutorial on LTSPICE from a Canadian University (Laurier).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Obviously I have missed some important part about AC waves. I will have to read something on this matter. But still, so I have to live with wrong diagrams showing waves up to 325V where I am working with 230V? Or is there some setting to correct this?

Comment: It's not incorrect. Just another way of measuring the same identical thing. If you charge a capacitor through a diode from your 230VAC (RMS) line you'll quickly see that the 325V is just as real as the 230VAC. In fact you'd have to do some math to see the 230 if you were looking at the waveform on an oscillscope- it goes from +325 to -325 and '230' is nowhere to be seen. You *could* (indirectly) see the 230 by adjusting a DC source to light an incandescent bulb until it was the same brightness and reading the DC voltage...

Comment: Oh god, for one moment I thought everything is fine, but so an oscilloscope would show 325V peaks in my outlet... Thanks, I got it, I will check your link for LTspice, and I will have to learn about electricity :)

Comment: Yet, I have to divide the peak voltage from the LTSPICE simulation diagrams by sqrt(2) to get a "human" readable voltage?

Comment: It's only so because your AC voltmeter is calibrated in RMS for sine wave. It's typically **lying** to you anyway- reading in average absolute voltage (about 207V) and adjusting the reading up by \$\pi\$/sqrt(8) ~= 1.11. Yet another way of measuring the same thing!

Comment: Yeah, but if my voltmeter is calibrated, then so should LTSPICE be ;-), else my simulation gives apples, my voltmeter( in my deadly power outlet ) gives pears and little stupid me thinks that physics is crazy :-)

Comment: Spehro Pefhany - You may want to review your formula. As written it should show VPEAK / SQRT(2).

Comment: @AndyZ If you insist on the grocery metaphor it's more like buying eggs at 2-1/2 dozen to the flat vs. buying them 30 at a time. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I must admit, I looked at 2 dozen - 1/2 dozen = 18 and could not get the 30, is that how you write two and a half, well I don't know a better way to write it. 2,5 sounds strange for a dozen :)

Answer (score 1):

That 230 V AC is the [RMS voltage](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/rms-voltage.html) !
Follow the link for an explanation.

What is boils down to is that if you take a resistor or a lightbulb and apply 230 V AC RMS (as coming from the mains) to it then it will use as much power as it would if, instead of AC you applied DC. To get the same power you would need to apply 230 V DC.

That 230 V RMS has a **peak value** of $$Vpeak = \sqrt[]{2} * Vrms$$

so that would be that 325 V

So mains voltage is:

230 V RMS = 325 V peak = 650 V peak-peak

Yes that looks silly but it is simply a matter of definition.
In general simulators use the Vpeak voltage so you need to fill in 325 V
and then you simulate the value of the mains voltage of 230 V AC RMS

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If it is just a matter of definition, then I can live with it, as long as I can configure LTSpice to show the correct scale for my 230V AC. So this is not real physics - it's just for correct calculations? = there are no 325V peaks in my power outlet? My view of electricity would be really shattered if my power outlet would produce peaks of 325V... I can't believe this could be the case

Comment: forgot @ in my first comment :) (where did my @FakeMoustache disappear?)

Comment: There *are* indeed 325V peaks in your 230V AC outlet. You have to understand that the "230V AC" number that you see is an [RMS (root-mean squared)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) representation. I believe this is done to make average power calculations more understandable when dealing with a time varying current, I(t), in the formula P(t) = I(t)^2*R.

Comment: @KnightsValour I start to believe that the whole electricity thing is a big scam, the avarage value I get is 0V, so I pay for using 0V and that's scam ;-) (please don't reply anything serious)

Comment: What you pay for is the **energy** delivered ! So 230V RMS relates to the energy so it is completely fair :-)

Comment: @FakeMoustache Nice try, but I don't believe you, I think you work for the electricity company :-P